# Overload the [dynamically-loaded] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There were something like 10 questions tagged with [dynamically-loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamically-loaded). It is a tag without tag info and is not used very much.

As I edited all the questions that used it, can we now delete this tag?

Comment: You should probably have asked this burmination request *before* single handedly removing the tag from all those posts, as that's how a burmination-request works; get community input before doing something.

Comment: Should I rollback all my changes and link the tags I've edited in my question?

Comment: My take is that since it were 10 questions and the tag had no tag info it's fine to burminate, but next time you'll want to ask beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already removed the tag from all the questions, it will be removed by the system automatically at 03:00 UTC.

Answer (score 5):

We have a [dynamic-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-loading) tag that is currently associated with 237 questions.

As such, the proper course of action would have been to merge [dynamically-loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamically-loaded) into [dynamic-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-loading) and create a permanent synonym.

As has been pointed out in [the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341722/overload-the-dynamically-loaded-tag#comment433683_341722) already:

> You should probably have asked this burmination [sic] request before single handedly removing the tag from all those posts, as that's how a burmination-request works; get community input before doing something.

Whether it's a burnination request, a retag request, or anything involving mass edits to multiple questions, you should attempt to reach a consensus on Meta first, before embarking on the project. Mass edits are disruptive, even when you have full editing privileges. I suppose this is sort of an edge case, since there were only 10 questions with the tag, but even still, creating a synonym seems like a better long-term solution, and one that would be less work for you and less disruptive for everyone. If you had asked on Meta *first*, that option could have been suggested.

Comment: Fine, I remember for next time. ;-)

Comment: @adriaan It's a meme from Trogdor on Homestar Runner; see [What does it mean to burninate a tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag)